# Is there a way to select rows based on a quantity column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains:

```
 id qty product_id
```

When selecting an order I get back:

```
 id qty product_id
 1   2   123
 2   1   234
```

Is there a way in mysql to select this instead?

```
 id qty product_id
 1   1   123
 1   1   123
 2   1   234
```

Kind of like an explode on `qty` column.

Comment: You should handle that in your program logic and not in SQL.

Comment: yeah thats what im doing. just wondering if there was a nice way to do it :)

Comment: There is no nice way to do it in SQL

Comment: you could do it in sql but you wouldn't like the answer

Comment: sounds good thanks :D